# LWC not covering the entire page when published with Experience Cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I've created and deployed my first LWC using Experience Cloud and when published, I'm seeing it's not covering all the page like it should.

Some grey lines are above and below my component not letting it expand.

[image]

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong but don't know how to fix it.

This is the component's url: https://idelatorreportfolio-dev-ed.develop.my.site.com/brm-calculator

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>BMR Calculator</h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2>What does your BRM means?</h2>
                <p class="slds-var-m-bottom_medium">Once you have measured your BRM, you can determine the minimum number of calories needed to sustain vital bodily functions while at complete rest.</p>
            </div>
            <form>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
:host(){
    --color-white: white;
    --color-black: black;
    --color-light-blue: rgb(73, 193, 232);
    --color-light-violet: rgb(237, 195, 237);
    --size-12: 12px;
    --size-14: 14px;
    --size-16: 16px;
}

.app{
    background-image: url(/sfsites/c/resource/BRMBackground);
    background-size: cover;
    max-height: 100vh;

}

.container{
    max-width: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: var(--color-light-blue);
    color: var(--color-white);
    padding: var(--size-16);
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.wrapper{
    background-color: var(--color-white);
    padding: var(--size-16);
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: var(--size-14);
}

h1{
    color: var(--color-black);
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

h2{
    font-size: 26px;
    color: var(--color-light-violet);
}


p{
    color: var(--color-light-blue);
    font-size: var(--size-12);
}
```